# ITMS-90429: Invalid Swift Support

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I archive my react-native app and put on the App Store Connect, I got this error :

```
ITMS-90429: Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib, libswiftDispatch.dylib, 
libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib, libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftMetal.dylib, 
libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftos.dylib, 
libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location 
/Payload/SafetifyMobileReact3.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location, rebuild your 
app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.
```

Don't find solution in any website...

I'm using XCode 11.6 and react-native 0.63.0

Comment: Found a solution, at this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-ADD_FRAMEWORK_TARGET, and search for "Embedded .dylib Files"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue almost spent a week and found a solution, at this link [ITMS-90429: Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib, libswiftMetal.dylib,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65749808/4524669)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error due to having added a dylib to my project directly, rather than in the form of a framework. This limitation is mentioned here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING-BUNDLE_ERRORS

> The following errors may indicate your app is embedding a dynamic library that is not packaged as a framework. Dynamic libraries outside of a framework bundle, which typically have the file extension .dylib, are not supported on iOS, watchOS, or tvOS, except for the system Swift libraries provided by Xcode.
>
> ...
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib,  libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location /Payload/<YourApp.app>/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.

By converting the dylib into a framework the issue was solved.