# ITMS-90429: Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib, libswiftMetal.dylib,

Tags: swift5, xcode12

I am facing a problem with Xcode 12.3, swift 5, and cocoapods-1.10.1 version when I want to publish my archive on Appstore Connect, everything goes well, but once the application sent I receive an e-mail from App Store Connect with the following error :

> ITMS-90429: Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib,
> libswiftMetal.dylib, libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, libswiftsimd.dylib,
> libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftos.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib,
> libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreLocation.dylib,
> libswiftAccelerate.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib,
> libswiftCoreData.dylib, libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib,
> libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
> libswiftAVFoundation.dylib, libswiftContacts.dylib,
> libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib,
> libswiftMediaPlayer.dylib, libswiftCloudKit.dylib,
> libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location
> /Payload/WoWonder.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected
> location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of
> Xcode, and resubmit it.

Comment: Hopefully, After spending a week on this issue. I resolved it by myself just unchecked ***Strip Siwft Symbols***  while ***App store connect distribution options***
ref: https://prntscr.com/y0x6y0

Answer (score 0):

Please search for .dylib files. It is not available in proper location. Please checkout this links, this will help you out.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1881/_index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error due to having added a dylib to my project directly, rather than in the form of a framework. This limitation is mentioned here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING-BUNDLE_ERRORS

> The following errors may indicate your app is embedding a dynamic library that is not packaged as a framework. Dynamic libraries outside of a framework bundle, which typically have the file extension .dylib, are not supported on iOS, watchOS, or tvOS, except for the system Swift libraries provided by Xcode.
>
> ...
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib, libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location /Payload/<YourApp.app>/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.

By converting the dylib into a framework the issue was solved

Comment: Hi! When I embed the dylib files in a xcframework, I got this error message:

**ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.**

Is there a solution for that?